# What are the Timer and Announce ports of ALSA's System MIDI client and how to use it?

Tags: alsa, midi

The command `aconnect -lio` always shows these entries:

```
client 0: 'System' [type=noyau]
    0 'Timer           '
    1 'Announce        '
client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=noyau]
    0 'Midi Through Port-0'
```

The “Midi Through” client has an obvious meaning, as it is standard in the MIDI world, and is easily used. The “Timer” port of the “System” client has a rather obvious abstract meaning, but there seems to be no documentation about it. The “Announce” port looks mysterious and is unknown of standard MIDI devices (or it is just to me). Searching the web about the “Timer” and “Announce” ports, for a long time, gave nothing.

**Questions:** Is there some pointers to learn more about the “Timer” and “Announce” ports of the “System” client? I mean, with answers to this kind of questions: what message can be received/sent from/to it, and how to start/stop/configure (especially for the “Timer”).

This is mainly a platform or system documentation question, but as it is also ALSA related, I'm unsure if it's best to post it here or on StackOverflow. Please, accept my apologizes if my guess was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

That's OK, I found a documentation for it, it was in ALSA API documentation (I just missed it on the first look):

[ALSA project - the C library reference (alsa-project.org)](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/seq.html)

> A sequencer core has two pre-defined system ports on the system client SND_SEQ_CLIENT_SYSTEM: SND_SEQ_PORT_SYSTEM_TIMER and SND_SEQ_PORT_SYSTEM_ANNOUNCE. The SND_SEQ_PORT_SYSTEM_TIMER is the system timer port, and SND_SEQ_PORT_SYSTEM_ANNOUNCE is the system announce port. In order to control a queue from a client, client should send a queue-control event like start, stop and continue queue, change tempo, etc. to the system timer port. Then the sequencer system handles the queue according to the received event. This port supports subscription. The received timer events are broadcasted to all subscribed clients.

About `SND_SEQ_PORT_SYSTEM_ANNOUNCE`:

> The latter port does not receive messages but supports subscription. When each client or port is attached, detached or modified, an announcement is sent to subscribers from this port.

Ex. from `SND_SEQ_PORT_SYSTEM_TIMER`, one may receive `SND_SEQ_EVENT_START` events and from `SND_SEQ_PORT_SYSTEM_ANNOUNCE`, one may receive `SND_SEQ_EVENT_PORT_SUBSCRIBED` events.

It appears I should have posted this on StackOverflow rather than on AskUbuntu. If any one with this capability see this post, please, move it to StackOverflow (the question and its answer may still be worth to others).